# laravel socialite error when user cancels

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I'm creating a laravel 5 app, that has social authentication inbound, now I have all the code to get the user, register it or log in in case the user exists, all works fine. The issue is when the user does not agreed to login with the social provider into my app(eg, press the cancel button), somebody knows how to handle that.

Now if I press the cancel button on the social login window then it throws a 400 Client error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use try-catch. Move all your code inside try block & in catch block redirect user to login page & show appropriate message.

Comment: @Vikas convert your comment into an answer to mark it resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use try-catch. Move all your login/registration code inside try block & inside catch block, redirect user to login page & show appropriate message

Answer (score 0):

The error comes because it redirects you to callback function without the code parameter in the URL and that is reason of showing exception. You can resolve it by adding a check in your callback function like as follows:

```
if (!$request->has('code') || $request->has('denied')) {
 return redirect('/signin');
}
```